# MS SQL 2014: Rewrite procedure into CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In MS SQL 2014 I've got a procedure that calculates years months and days in a way that from **5 years 14 months and 35 days** I get **6 years 3 months and 5 days**. Because I can use neither procedure (even temp) nor function in my code, I need that calculation into e.g. CTE. Can anyone help?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #YearsMonthsDaysSum @EmpId INT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Years INT, @Months INT, @Days INT
SELECT @Years=Years, @Months=Months, @Days=Days FROM #Table1 WHERE EmpId=@EmpId
IF @Days<0
BEGIN
    SET @Months=@Months-(1-CAST(@Days/30 as INT))
    SET @Days=@Days+30*(1-CAST(@Days/30 as INT))
END
IF @Months<0
BEGIN
    SET @Years=@Years-(1-CAST(@Months/12 as INT))
    SET @Months=@Months+12*(1-CAST(@Months/12 as INT))
END
IF(@Days>30)
BEGIN
    SET @Months=@Months+CAST(@Days/30 as INT)
    SET @Days=@Days%30
END
IF(@Months>=12)
BEGIN
    SET @Years=@Years+CAST(@Months/12 as INT)
    SET @Months=@Months%12
END

SELECT EmpId=@EmpId, Years=@Years, Months=@Months, Days=@Days
END
```

Comment: What about leap years? How many days in a month? Need more context here

Comment: Taking month lengths and leap years into account would require a date to start from. If you have that, you can use `DATEADD` to calculate the result date (`SELECT DATEADD(YEAR, 5, DATEADD(MONTH, 14, DATEADD(DAY, 35, '20000101'))) AS FixedDate`), then `DATEPART` to get the normalized differences. Without a start date, you need a fixed length for all months, which is unlikely to be useful.

Comment: `CROSS APPLY` is handful to make claculations like this.

Answer (score 2):

It would be easier to first calculate the total number of days, then get back to years,months and days.

```
declare @empid int = 1
Declare @table1 table (empid int, years int, months int, [days] int)
insert into @table1 values (1,5,14,35)

;with YearsMonthsDaysSum_cte as
(
    select days/(30*12) years,(days%(30*12))/30 months,days%30 [days]
    from (
        select  [days] + months * 30 + years * 30*12 [days]
        from @table1) x
    )

select * from YearsMonthsDaysSum_cte
```

Comment: Perferct! Thanks very much, Peter.

Answer (score 0):

Using CROSS APPLY for in-line calculations eliminates CTE. Just

```
SELECT EmpId, step2.Years, step2.Months, step2.Days
    FROM #Table1 t
    CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT totaldays = [days] + months * 30 + years * 30*12 [days]
    ) step1 
    CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT 
        years = totaldays/(30*12), 
        months = totaldays%(30*12))/30,
        [days] = totaldays%30 
    ) step2
  -- JOIN, WHERE or any other Sql follows
;
```

More steps can be added for complex calculations, leap years for example.